# How can I get the indices of children in a HTML ul sortable list, using jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable, html-lists

I have a list that is dynamically populated, I want to get the indices of children of that list. 
The list is an unordered sortable list, created using jQuery.

Here is the code:

```
 $(function getIndex(){
            var i=0;
            for (i = 0; i < $("#questionList").length; i++)
                questionOrder[i] = $("#questionList").children().index(); //not working
    });
```

Comment: can you give a more detailed code ? if you can, post a sample list plus your code on jsfiddle so I can test it and see what you're doing wrong ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function getIndex(){
            var i=0;
            for (i = 0; i < $("#questionList").length; i++)
                questionOrder[i] = $("#questionList").children().get(i).index();
    });
```

You have to get the specific child in that children array and then get the index